Add structured logging parameters with object instance values
Assume following object model:
public class FooManager {
    private ILogger _logger;
    private Dictionary<string, Foo> _instances = ...

    // CRUD interface
}

public class Foo {
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    private ILogger _logger;
    private Dictionary<string, Bar> _bars = ...

    // Some stateful threaded logic
}

public class Bar {
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    private ILogger _logger;

    // Some stateful threaded logic
}


I want all log messages generated by instances of Foo to contain a prefix with instance Id:
... [<foo_id>] <message>


I want all log messages generated by instances of Bar to contain a prefix with Foo and Bar instance Ids (assume that Bar can obtain parent Foo's Id if necessary):
... [<foo_id>] [<bar_id>] <message>



I'm using NLog and following examples on setting it up with DI and using ILogger all over the place. Here is how I currently initialise the app:
...
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddNLog();
...

What is the cleanest and most performant way to achieve above behaviour? Ideally I'd like to keep using DI for logger injection and keep the resulting code testable either by being able to mock logger interface or by easily injecting some test logger instance in unit-tests.
At first I was hoping to leverage NLog's Logger.WithProperty to create custom instances of loggers with pre-defined properties but I soon realised that I can't do it if I keep using ILogger.
I briefly considered switching from ILogger to Logger, but I had some concerns about the testability of the resulting code (being unable to mock Logger);
I then looked at ILogger's BeginScope but it does not seem to produce the behaviour I need because:

ILogger seems to be injected as a singleton
I'm capturing IDisposable scope returned by ILogger.BeginScope in the instance of the Foo/Bar, but they seem get mixed up on the same stack and I get logs from Foo instance which contains [<bar_id>].


I'm capturing IDisposable scope returned by ILogger.BeginScope in the instance of the Foo/Bar

Here is what I mean by above:
public class Foo {
    ...
    private ILogger _logger;
    private IDisposable? _loggerScope;

    public Foo(ILogger<Foo> logger) {
        _logger = logger;
        _loggerScope = _logger.BeginScope("{foo_id}", [Id]);
    }

    public void foo() {
        _logger.LogInformation("hello world");
    }
}


The easy solution would be to ensure all logging performed into the Foo-class always had Id as message-property. Ex. _logger.LogInformation("{FooId} Hello World", Id);. But yes NLog WithProperty makes the code cleaner, but the abstraction ILogger has a cost together with lowest common denominator.

"but the abstraction ILogger has a cost together with lowest common denominator."
@RolfKristensen Can you rephrase this please? What do you mean by it?

Just trying to say the cost of abstractions like ILogger is that you loose access to the good stuff. And just have rely on the minimal features available.
